# Importing Packages PyCharm

Tags: python, pydev

Galera, estou com um problema ao tentar utilizar um projeto no pycharm.. utilizo o xhtml2pdf e ao tentar debugar aparece este erro :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem eu já tenho os packages adicionado no projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém faz ideia de como posso arrumar isso ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[RESOLVIDO]**

Para quem tiver o mesmo problema saiba, a ultima versão do reportlab é a 3.x.x porem o xhtml2pdf/pisa não aceita... para ele é requerido a versão 2.5 do reportlab porem isso da para quebrar da seguinte maneira :

Abra o Arquivo Pisa_util.py

Troque o trecho :

```
if not (reportlab.Version[0] == "2" and reportlab.Version[2] >= "1"):
  raise ImportError("Reportlab Version 2.1+ is needed!")
```

por

```
if not (reportlab.Version[:3]>="2.1"):
    raise ImportError("Reportlab Version 2.1+ is needed!")

REPORTLAB22 = (reportlab.Version[:3]>="2.1")
```

Por hora isso resolve.

Answer (score 3):

O *package* está presente mas o método em uso para verificar a versão do mesmo está desatualizado.

Como já existe uma resposta fazendo uso de *string literals*, vou deixar uma alternativa fazendo uso de [tuples](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Think_Python/Tuples) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> de inteiros:

```
_reportlab_version = tuple(map(int, reportlab.Version.split('.')))
if _reportlab_version < (2,1):
    raise ImportError("Reportlab Version 2.1+ is needed!")

REPORTLAB22 = _reportlab_version >= (2, 2)
```

---

<sup>A solução é referida [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22077096/352449) do SOEN pelo utilizador @hanleyhansen.</sup>